# Why am I missing a reference?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, tfs

When I'm building in TFS I have something like this:

```
App_Start\BundleConfig.cs (2): The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist 
in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  

Global.asax.cs (3): The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the 
namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

App_Start\BundleConfig.cs (9): The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be 
found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I've already looked through this links:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore-with-team-build

But nothing seems to help :/  On my local copy everything build and runs ok. I'm googling for any solution but nothing seems to help. I have also deleted the packages folder so that TFS could download it (at least that what I have found on the net) but this doesn't help either. I'm running out of ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Search the build logs and confirm that the build process is downloading the missing NuGet packages.

Also verify that your build machine has .NET 4.5 installed. Judging by the [MSDN page for the namespace System.Web.Optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the package only supports .NET 4.5 and above.

Comment: I don't think you can use it on a 4.0 project; see my updated answer.

Comment: yeah I've seen it but we have an mvc4 project in our solutions and it's building fine it did not havve such issues. I've changed the freamweork in the properties from 4 to 4.5 maybe that will help? And I've also seen that I had in the *.csproj file in the xml version of the librrary set to 1.00 but the path was to 1.3 something...I've changed that to 1.0 and I'll se what will happen

Comment: yeah but when I have created the mvc 4 project it added for me this file (I've used the template called ASP.NET MVC 4 application) and this was all in. But it seems when I try to check in it says that I'm missing that file

Comment: Your local machine has .NET 4.5 installed, so it works fine. The build machine needs the new version of .NET to be able to build against System.Web.Optimization.

Comment: ok I understand that but how it is posiible that we have also an MVC4 project which is using the same DLL and it's running and building fine. My isn't...

Comment: Make sure that the build machine isn't downloading a newer version of the package than what you are using locally and see if there are any differences there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I should write you that I have fixed the problem.

It seems that in the package folder in the solution the dll's were missing. I've added the items to the packages foleder. In fact I did it last time but it also did not help. But today i've noticed that the libraries that my app was looking for were EXCLUDED from the check in. I don't know why but I've included everything what has excluded. Going by path that Babak Naffas i had the problem probably with the fact that on the build server there is .net 4.0 installed. So i've also changed the traget framework attribute from net45 to net40. Now it's building :)